# Missing properties in IgniteUI after upgrade from TypeScript 1.0 to 1.8

Tags: javascript, typescript1.8, ignite-ui

We are upgrading our TypeScript project from version 1.0 to TypeScript 1.8.
We are now also using the latest IgniteUI definitions file (v 16.1), which (following the Typescript version change) does not work with our existing object initialization (see error at the bottom of this post).

This is our existing TypeScript code using IgniteUI igTextEditor:

```
            $(this.textinput).igTextEditor({
                maxLength: this.maxChars,
                textMode: sTextMode,
                listItems: [""],
                buttonType: "dropdown",
                dropDownListOpening: function (evt, ui) {
                    formBase.setActiveForm(self.formID);
                    self.buttonClicked();
                    return false;
                },

                // Validator Options
                validatorOptions: {
                    onblur: true,
                    onchange: false,
                    required: this.required,
                    notificationOptions: {
                        direction: "right",
                        showIcon: "true",
                        mode: "popover"
                    },
                    custom: function (value, fieldOptions) {
                        if (self.showError) {
                          self.showError = false;
                            if (self.errorMessage.length > 0) {
                                $(this.element).igValidator("option", "errorMessage", self.errorMessage);
                            }
                            return false;
                        }

                        self.validate(value);
                        return true;
                    }

                },
                keyup: function (evt, ui) { if (evt.keyCode == 13) { $(evt.currentTarget).blur() } },
                focus: function () { formBase.setActiveForm(self.formID) }
            });
```

Here's the relevant interface definitions from igniteui.d.ts:

```
interface IgTextEditor {
    textMode?: string;
    maxLength?: number;
    includeKeys?: string;
    excludeKeys?: string;
    toUpper?: boolean;
    toLower?: boolean;
    listMatchIgnoreCase?: boolean;
    listMatchOnly?: boolean;
    listMatchContains?: boolean;
    listAutoComplete?: boolean;
}

interface JQuery {
    igTextEditor(options: IgTextEditor): JQuery;
    igTextEditor(optionLiteral: string, options: IgTextEditor): JQuery;
    igTextEditor(optionLiteral: string, optionName: string, optionValue: any): JQuery;
    igTextEditor(optionLiteral: string, optionName: string): any;
    igTextEditor(methodName: string): any;
}
```

The only change in this code from igniteui.d.ts was from:

`igTextEditor(optionLiteral: string, optionName: any, optionValue: any): JQuery;`
to:

```
igTextEditor(optionLiteral: string, optionName: string, optionValue: any): JQuery;
```

After the upgrade to TypeScript 1.8 we are getting the following error:

**error TS2345**: Build: Argument of type '{ [x: number]: undefined; maxLength: number; textMode: string; listItems: string[]; buttonType: s...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

**Question**: Considering TypeScript is much stricter with type validation in 1.8, and casting to < any > is not an option, what would the community suggest is the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: What version of Ignite UI are you using?

Comment: Version 16.1 of Ignite UI - now updated the question, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay
In typescript 1.6 was added "Strict object literal assignment checking".
This means that you can not pass as parameter object which not meet interface !!EXACTLY!!

So if parameter object interface declare fields {field1, field2} - you may pass {field1, field2} ONLY but not {field1} or {field1, field2, field3}

Example:

var obj: { id: number };
obj = {id: 1, name: "my object"} - WILL BE AN ERROR - because 'name' not defined in obj declaration.

To pass additional fields need to use indexers

var obj: { id: number, [x:string] any };
and you may pass any additional fields

---

Just remember about strict types and check if all objects 100% meet interfaces (maybe something used from obsolete IgniteUI)